# Swift Can't initializing UIImageView and causes fatal error: unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, xcode8, xcode8.2

I'm using xcode 8.2.1

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is the code,

```
class ShowMediaViewController: UIViewController {
var image: UIImage?
var titreText: String!
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
//i tried @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! but didn't work
@IBOutlet weak var titre: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if image != nil {

        //crashes here, because imageView is nil
        imageView.image = image
    } else {
        print("image not found")
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

The code seems to  crash at this line

```
imageView.image = image
```

I think is because imageView is nil?, cause i tried

```
print(image)
```

and came out fine, and then 
`print(imageView)`, it causes fatal error
But i did initializing it

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Maybe something's wrong with my storyboard?

Any help would be much appreciated

**

> UPDATE 1
>   Connection Inspector

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAzAY.png)

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSJSv.png)
**

Comment: can you show pic of connection inspector of that imageView?

Comment: In Storyboard, right+click `ImageView` and triple check that 1) the connection to your outlet is right and 2) there is no other connection (maybe still existing after renaming the outlet or such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried following steps. then It works.

Try these things,

1. Check the imageView bind to the storyBoard properly.
2. Clean and Build the project.

if not works

3. Close and restart XCode
4. Remove imageView from storyBoard add again imageView and bind again.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a connection from your view to the outlet. Check these:-

1) clicking on a dot next to the outlet in the code shows a connection to the storyboard
2) the outlets window for the image shows a connection to the code